# Silverlight Exception Message is different on other machines

Tags: silverlight, xaml, exception, silverlight-5.0, xamlparseexception

I am currently stuck with the following problem and running desperately out of ideas, any clues are welcome!

We are using a custom built framework that loads what we call "pages" on demand for the UI, each of these "pages" is a self contained Silverlight XAML that is loaded on demand via:

```
XamlReader.Load(somePageXamlFile)
```

It may happen that a part inside this xaml is outdated, so a try / catch block ensures that a XAMLParseException is caught and the respective error handled.

Our current error handling is heavily based on the message of the exception, e.g. we expect a message like this:

> "The type 'someType' could not be found. [Line: x Position: y]"

-> we parse the message string and replace the essential xaml parts with custom logic to make it valid again and display info for administrators.

The problem:
Some test machines throw the same exception, but with a different message!
Errormessage there:

> "Error 2502 An error has occured."

This breaks our "safety net" logic for this case and currently we can not figure out any reason for this.

Solutions or proposals are very welcome, 
thanks in advance!

-Steve

Comment: Is it possible that you get a `TargetInvocationException` with the Message `Error 2502 An error has occured.` If so you should also handle this exception type and check if the InnerException is of type `XamlParseException`.

Comment: I suspect there is a difference between the Silverlight clients the machines are running (version or developer/non-developer)

Comment: @Jehof: The exception is exactly of type `XamlParseException` and contains no inner exception, already checked this.

@RobJacobs: I will check into these versions on the respective systems, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Update @RobJacobs: I checked the installed Silverlight version, as well as .Net Framework Version and they are identical (all 64 Bit & same version number), also the problem seems unrelated to OS (have it running and failing on Win 7 SP1 & Win 8 the same)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long and hard search we came down to the following: The clients and the development machines seem to have different versions of the Microsoft agcore.dll (development machines have 2 different version in different paths). As this is the core of the exception we suppose this is the reason for the different error message - we were unable to fix this issue however (we cannot be sure what dll our clients get during SL5 download...) therefore we decided to rewrite the whole code segment to not make use of the exception message text at all. Lesson learned.

Thanks for the feedback. -Steve